# Is there priority in a SPARQL OR filter instruction?

Tags: filter, sparql, rdf, boolean-operations

I'd like to know whether the order of the words gives or changes the priority in an OR filter SPARQL instruction. For example

```
FILTER( regex(STR(?keywords), "test1", "i")
        || regex(STR(?keywords), "test2", "i")
        || regex(STR(?keywords), "test3", "i")
        || regex(STR(?keywords), "test4", "i")
        || regex(STR(?keywords), "test5", "i") )
```

Does this query indicate that *test1* has more priority than *test2* in the filtering of the results? In other words, does it affect the order of the results? In case where I am limiting the results to 20 for example which is lower than the total (let's say 60), will I get the results of *test1* first and then *test2*?

If not, is there a way to establish such a priority?

Comment: What would a "higher priority" result in? The filter arguments dont change the data in any way, so their order will have no influence on the result (maybe on performance though).

Comment: @Sirko sorry my question was not complete, I will update it. I forget to add that I'm limiting the results to 20 for example. in the case where there is more than 20, will I get the results of test1 first ?

Comment: I don't think, that there is anything in the standard to specify this. If you want to give a priority to some entries, you have to use an ORDER clause.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does this query indicates that test1 has more priority than test2 in
>   the filtering the results ? in other words, does it affect the order
>   of the results? in case where I am limiting the results to 20 for
>   example which is lower than the total (let's say 60), will I get the
>   results of test1 first and then test2 ?

When there's no **order by** at the end of the query, the order is not specified, so an implementation could certainly change the ordering based on the **filter**, but it doesn't seem particularly likely, at least not in any obvious way.  When you ask, "will I get the results of test1 first and then test2," it suggests a bit a of a misunderstanding about what **filter** does.  **Filter** is a way of specifying some conditions that a result must satisfy in order to be included in the result set.  Conceptually, before the **filter**, there is a list of results in a working result set, and then the **filter** test is applied to each one, and the ones that satisfy the test are kept.  There are no "results" of test1 or test2 in any meaningful sense.  Different ways of applying the test could affect the ordering, e.g., depending on whether its:

```
final results = {}
for (result in working results) 
  for (testi in tests)
    if result passes test
      add result to final results
```

or

```
final results = {}
for (testi in tests)
  for (result in working results) 
    if result passes test
      add result to final results
```

Since final results is a *set*, you'd end up with the same set, but since the results are eventually provided as a list, it's conceivable that this could affect the order you see the results in.  But as I said above, it's unlikely that you'd get any reliable, meaningful difference this way.

> if not, is there a way to establish such a priority?

If you want to **order** the results in some way, you'll need to figure out how to get that priority, and then you can order by it.  For instance, in your case, you could do something like:

```sql
select ?keywords {
  values ?test { "test1" "test2" "test3" }
  #-- get a binding for ?keywords...
  filter regex(str(?keywords), ?test)
}
order by ?test
```

In this case, since the values of **?test** have a reliable ordering, you can order the results based on which values of **?test** matched.  Of course, if **?keywords** matches more than one value of **?test**, you'll see it multiple times in the results.

If the criteria isn't as simple as a string, you can still use **values** to specify the priority:

```sql
select ?keywords {
  values (?test ?priority) { ("test1" 3) ("test2" 0) ("test3" 5)}
  #-- get a binding for ?keywords...
  filter regex(str(?keywords), ?test)
}
order by ?priority
```